# wordpress gallery plugin won't show gallery online

Tags: plugins, plugin-nextgen-gallery

i have installed two different gallery plugins (Slideshow Gallery and Nextgen-gallery) i need both of them since they display photos in different ways and i need'em for different pages. I installed previously the "NextGen-gallery" and it works fine. Than i installed the "Slideshow Gallery" but when i put the short code into the page,it doesn't display anything! It's blank! i tried in a different website to leave just "Slideshow gallery" plugin and it did show up.

Is there a problem to install 2 gallery plugins in a website?? What can i do to keep them both??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is difficult to answer without [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

May converge CSS styles when you put shortcode he tries to call the desired gallery and called multiple styles CSS

Comment: Please try to explain that. I cannot really follow.

Comment: so what can i do to differ the css files,so that when a gallery is shown,it calls the proper css??